# Algorithm for heatmap with intensity

Tags: algorithm, math

I am working on a heatmap(maybe this is an incorrect term for this situation) where the user will have points that contain coordinates and an intensity value. Every implementation I've seen is basing the color off density of points, which is not what I am looking for. I've been reasearching the topic for a day or two now and have been trying to find out the best ways of generating such a heatmap from coordinates.

I have been currently looking into multivariable kernel density estimations and am not sure if this is the correct path to be taking. I had the idea of using 3d vectors with x and y being coordinates and the z being the intensity but I am not sure if this will work. All the examples I have seen are basing color off density of points.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
for p in points{ // loop over all measured points
    // points are stored in a dict with the key being x+y*NUM_COL
    let pX = p.key % NUM_COL
    let pY = p.key / NUM_COL
    let intensity = points[p.key]!.getAvg()

    // loop over all surrounding points within square with size of radius * 2
    for i in 0..<Int(pow(Double(2*RADIUS),2)){
        let dX = (i % (2*RADIUS)) - RADIUS
        let dY = (i / (2*RADIUS)) - RADIUS
        let x = pX + dX
        let y = pY + dY
        let dist = (pow(Double(x-pX),2) + pow(Double(y-pY),2)).squareRoot()
        // check if coordinate is in bounds and is not a measured value
        if (x < 0 || x >= NUM_COL || y < 0 || y >= NUM_ROW || dist > Double(RADIUS) || points[x+y*NUM_COL] != nil){
            continue
        }
        grid[y][x] += intensity * (1 - (dist/RADIUS))
    }
}
```

which results in something like(black dots are measured points):

[image: Heatmap]

My question is, what could I do to improve this, both performance wise and visually?
Should I keep pushing down the path of mvkde's? Is there a better way of finding values with less looping?

NOTES:

- picture was generated with 50 measured points, screen(768, 1024), grid(768, 1024), radius of 40 and took 6:21 to generate data and draw to screen
- switching to grid size of (768/4, 1024/4) and radius of 15 it took 15-20 seconds and this was the generated pic:[image: lower res]
- I am hoping to get this to use as an overlay on a dynamic map(scrolling and zooming will occur) with a data set of anywhere between 100 and 50000 measured points(although I am thinking if I did this I would need to combine some points). But even if the overlay took under 30 seconds to appear over the map that would be fine

Comment: If you are not looking for a density-based map, then what are you looking for?

Comment: @NicoSchertler a map that would use a value like temperature or something like that. Lets say you measured temperature in 500 spots, I am looking for something to smooth that data. Currently my method just uses a linear drop off bases off distance from measured point

Comment: Then you are looking for scattered data interpolation. There are a bunch of methods.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was "scattered data interpolation" thanks to @NicoSchertler